# How likely is it that the newly reached agreement between Stack Exchange and the community isn't going to end the moderation strike?

Tags: discussion, moderation-strike

An agreement has been reached between the striking community 'moderators and members' and Stack Exchange Inc.

However from what I collected, this has not resulted in immediate termination of the moderation strike. Votes are being gathered network-wide on whether the reached agreement is satisfactory and sufficient to end the strike.

I have to say this is surprising as I expected the strike to end as soon as an agreement has been reached, which raises the question:

How likely do you think the heavier votes are going to be in the pan of 'not to end the strike'?

If such an unexpected event happened, do you think there will be some sort of internal disturbance between the voters on both sides?

Comment: Speculating like this doesn't seem very useful, since we should have an answer quite soon. Keep in mind that strike action is not exactly centrally organized; many people will act on their own initiative regardless.

Comment: For transparency, there are currently 106 votes in favor of ending the strike, and 6 in favor of continuing.

Comment: So if this voting is representative to the majority (which we don't really know, but can only assume), the answer to you question is: **Highly unlikely**. Also, I agree with Karl and can't really see the point of speculation like this..

Comment: @Mithical Trust me, I hope the strike ends sooner rather than later

Answer (score 14):

Its very unlikely, short of something amazingly massively shockingly stupid from either side.

With the core issues resolved to the satisfaction of both negotiating parties, and general support of the conclusions the main issues leading to the strike appear resolved. There's other problems to deal with.

Least on the side of the moderators, I don't think there's any particular desire to burn bridges, salt the earth, and otherwise create strife. People went on strike  with a very particular, narrow scope, they have for most part been met, and we're looking to 'what next'.

Also, technically speaking "If such an unexpected event happened, do you think there will be some sort of internal disturbance between the voters on both sides?" - least as far as the company goes, their negotiator is essentially plenipotentiary and reports directly to the CEO as of the time of the post. If communication on that end is that bad, we have worse problems.

On the moderators side, We've had lots of experience dealing with differences of opinion. We're unlikely to hurl metaphorical chairs at each other

I think its worth worrying at how we  *got here* and *where we're going*, rather than *what's the worst that could happen*.